# Process to clone multiple TFS repositories

Tags: git, powershell, github, tfs

We're currently trying to migrate some repositories from TFS to Git. But there are a few problems that I'm faced with and I could use some help in defining a process.

We have different products and have folders in TFS that correspond to those. For instance, `Application 1`, `Application 2`, `Product 3` etc. When I use `git tfs list-remote-branches <tfs url>`: the results that I see of branches that can be cloned are like so:

```
$/Application 1/some folder1/some subfolder1 [*]
|
+- $/Application 1/some folder1/some subfolder1/v.15/DLL files

$/Application 2/some folder2/some subfolder2 [*]
|
+- $/Application 2/some folder2/some subfolder2/v.14/DLL files
|  |  $Application 2/some folder2/some subfolder2/v.20/LayoutDesigns
```

The above snippet is a sample of the type of results that I get when I use the `git tfs list-remote-branches` command. I can clone these repos successfully with by using:

```
git tfs clone <tfs url> <repo path> --branches=all
```

However, there's a problem with this. I'm trying to define a process where doing all of this will be easy. I understand that I can write a script for this and I'm trying to work on that. But the problem I have is that I cannot clone `$/Application 1` or `$/Application 2` directly. The above is just a sample, whereas in reality there are many more branches that I need cloned. Doing them all in this order looks as if they'll be very unorganized.

I have tried to use "Convert to branch" from Visual Studio Source Explorer and tried to convert `$/Application 1` and other folders (`Application 2` and `Product 3`) into branches but it says that the branch already exists so it cannot convert it.

Is there a smooth and efficient way in which I can clone these TFS repositories and convert them to git? As of now, the process might get very jumbled up because `git tfs clone` makes folders of each individual branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Migrating a TFVC to git is a tricky things due to the differences between the 2 VCS tools.

git-tfs is trying to help but depending on the degree of convoluted TFVC history could be unable to migrate it if you try to ask it to migrate branches.

Because with git-tfs, you have 2 possibilities:

1. Try to migrate branches
2. Migrate with "flat" history

## 1. Migrating with branch support

You need to clone one of the branches returned by `git tfs list-remote-branches`.

Most of the times, you will want to clone the ones highlighted with `[*]`.

If I understand well your problem, you will want to clone all the top branches with all the linked branches ( with `--branches=all` ) i.e.:

```
git tfs clone <tfs url> "$/Application 1/some folder1/some subfolder1" --branches=all
git tfs clone <tfs url> "$/Application 2/some folder2/some subfolder2" --branches=all
...
```

If everything went well, each clone will give you a git repository with the branch cloned and all the other branches linked into it.

For example, for `Application 1`, you will end up in your git repository with 2 "pseudo/tfvc" git remote: `tfs/default`will correspond to the branch cloned and every other branches will have there own "tfvc" remote

After that you will be able to keep it like that or try to combine all the "Application" repositories with git.

## 2. Migrating with flat history

It is done using the `--branches=none` option.
You could clone the TFVC folder you want or even the root repository but it will get the history of just this scope and won't try to

That's the thing to do when the previous method failed.
As a result you know have a git history and you could either keep it like that (but most of the time it won't be really useful) or try to recreate the history using `git` commands (like `git subtree`). But it will be far from perfect.

You could find some more documentation for git-tfs here: https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs#use-git-tfs

Comment: Yes, that is how I want them cloned. If I enter the path of `"$/Application 1/some folder1/some subfolder1"`, I end up with a "some subfolder"` which contains the contents however, I lose the previous path. All in all, it makes for a very complex and convoluted solution. I'm trying to make it so that I can just clone `$/Application 1` in this case and have all t he branches associated with it be cloned as well. However, `$/Application 1" cannot be cloned as it is not listed with a ` [*] `.